# Oracle STANDARD_HASH result show different result while using different platform

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, codeigniter-3, toad, navicat

I get a problem when doing queries with different platforms using Oracle. The results of the query indicate the difference in output.
First I used the "Toad for Oracle Database" application and the results like this:

[image]

The results showed perfect results, as I wanted.

But when I do queries on different platforms, namely PHP Codeigniter and Navicat (it may also apply to other platforms). The results are different as in this picture:

[image]

Following are the queries that I am trying to run but do not work on different platforms.

```
select STANDARD_HASH(sysdate) from dual;
```

Comment: `standard_hash` returns a `raw` data type.  My guess is that not all of the front ends you're using know how to handle `raw` correctly or are treating the `raw` as binary data rather than trying to convert it to a string to be displayed.

Comment: are there alternatives other than using standard_hash? i'm trying ora_hash but it just  return number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `RAWTOHEX`.  This will convert the returned value from a RAW to a VARCHAR2, which should be more easily understood by all SQL clients.  (As Justin pointed out this is probably a client issue, not a problem with `STANDARD_HASH`.)

```
select rawtohex(standard_hash(sysdate)) the_hash from dual;

THE_HASH
----------------------------------------
FBC14021D134F922420086D291906B0B0D783421
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, this really help my problem